# No module named 'augmentations'?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I'm getting this error. It doesn't seem to find the augmentations module. I'm trying to use basicsr for model training.I already tried to install the augmentation module, albumentation, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me and explain how to solve this?

How it's being imported:

```
import os.path
import random
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
import torch.utils.data as data
import data.util as util
import sys
sys.path.append('../codes/scripts')
sys.path.append('../codes/data')
**import augmentations # Here shows the module import error**
```

As it is being used below:

```
# Random Crop (reduce computing cost and adjust images to correct size first)
            if img_HR.shape[0] > HR_size or img_HR.shape[1] > HR_size:
                #Here the scale should be in respect to the images, not to the training scale (in case they are being scaled on the fly)
                scaleor = img_HR.shape[0]//img_LR.shape[0]
                img_HR, img_LR = augmentations.random_crop_pairs(img_HR, img_LR, HR_size, scaleor)
```

Console error:

```
  File "D:\basicsrtrainmodel\BasicSR\codes\data\LRHROTF_dataset.py", line 12, in <module>
    import augmentations
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'augmentations'
```

Someone help me please?

Comment: `**import` Is this typo?

Comment: How to solve this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data.util'`

Comment: Did you install a module called "augmentations"?  There certainly isn't one built-in.

Comment: From your first paragraphs it sounds like this is the module/package you're trying to use:
https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/blob/master/README.md

Based on their documentation, it looks like you should be using `import albumentations`, not `import augmentations`